# Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com.eu.cas.ms -UseWebLogin hangs with a blank window

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I'm trying to connect to a site where I'll try to upload some documents, here is what I try to do:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url  https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com.eu.cas.ms -UseWebLogin
```

What happens is it just opens a blank window and hangs.

What I have tried to do:

- `Connect-PnPOnline -Url  https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com.eu.cas.ms/sites/<my-site> -UseWebLogin` (use the full pat h to the site)
- `Connect-PnPOnline -Url  https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com/sites/<my-site> -UseWebLogin`  (use that path before it was redirected)
- `Connect-PnPOnline -Url  https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com.eu.cas.ms -UseWebLogin` (same only with the root)

Logging into the site on the web works fine however, as does `Connect-PnPOnline -Url  https://<mysite>.sharepoint.com.eu.cas.ms/sites/<my-site> -Credentials (Get-Credential)`

I'm on Windows 10, PowerShell version 5.1 and I'm using SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline version 3.13.1909.0.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this would be appreciated.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue.I have the same configurations mentioned in the question

Comment: I just reproduced it. I don't doubt that it works on most systems but on this particular system (that I don't control) it doesn't work and I hoped someone had seen this issue before.

Comment: 0

I am seeing this issue now whilst working in the ISE ( ironically VSCode +PoSH tools has an know issue with running scripts).

PowerShell verions 5.1.18362.145

SharePointPnPPowerShellOnnline 3.14.1910.1

I guess one thing I could do is upgrade my PS 5 version